# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, list, pandas, time, time-series

I have trouble with Bollinger Band algorithm. I want to apply this algorithm to my time series data.

The code:

```
length = 1440

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(speed)

ave = pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(speed,length)

sd = pd.stats.moments.rolling_std(speed,length=1440)

upband = ave + (sd*2)

dnband = ave - (sd*2)

print np.round(ave,3), np.round(upband,3), np.round(dnband,3)
```

Input:

```
speed=[96.5, 97.0, 93.75, 96.0, 94.5, 95.0, 94.75, 96.0, 96.5, 97.0, 94.75, 97.5, 94.5, 96.0, 92.75, 96.5, 91.5, 97.75, 93.0, 96.5, 92.25, 95.5, 92.5, 95.5, 94.0, 96.5, 94.25, 97.75, 93.0]
```

Result of "ave" variable:

[1440 rows x 1 columns]      0
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
5  NaN
6  NaN
7  NaN
8  NaN
9  NaN
10 NaN
11 NaN
12 NaN
13 NaN
14 NaN
15 NaN
16 NaN
17 NaN

Comment: As i understand the documentation of rolling_mean you should pass a Series or a DataFrame to the rolling_mean and not a list. (See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html#pandas.rolling_mean)

Comment: Thank you, I converted list into df, now I have an another error. I have a NaN result as a result of ave and sd variables. @StefanReinhardt

Comment: this is caused by the length attibute...

Comment: If you have another question please open another question. Do not change your question as you solve one problem and find another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point is, as i allready mentioned in the comment rolling_mean needs a DataFrame
you can achieve this by inserting the line

```
speed = pd.DataFrame(data=speed)
```

before the `ave = ...` line. 
Nonetheless you also missed to define the window attribute in rolling_std
(See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_std.html)

Comment: I have added speed = pd.DataFrame(data=speed) but I get NaN result again. @StefanReinhardt