# Fill density plots with color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, density-plot

I have two density plot, one above the other. How can I fill the area under the curves with 2 different colors and also add some transparency so that the overlapped region is noticeable.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys 
import seaborn as sns

x=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
y=[1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]
sns.distplot(x, hist=False,color="green")
sns.distplot(y, hist=False,color="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried `sns.kdeplot(x, hist=False, color="green", shade=True)`?
Apparently they create the same curve.

From what I can tell it is transparent by default, which should fulfill your requirements.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
y=[1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]
sns.kdeplot(x, color="green", shade=True)
sns.kdeplot(y, color="blue", shade=True)
plt.show()
```

[seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html)

Here is the resulting graph:

[image: Graph result]

Comment: there is no shade parameter in distplot

Comment: "_We can see that if we use the kdeplot() function in seaborn, we get the same curve. This function is used by distplot(), but it provides a more direct interface with easier access to other options when you just want the density estimate:_" - From Seaborn documentation link above.



Basically, use `kdeplot()` to see if you get the same curve.

Comment: I edited the answer so that there is code formatting.

Comment: @Eqomatic looks like you have to replace `hist=False` to `shade=True` in your answer for the `kdeplot` approach.

Comment: Answer has been changed to reflect these differences, thank you!

Comment: Why do I get this error with your code above ?
  
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203484/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-dtype), it looks like you could use a `dataframe` as a wrapper for your x & y data.

Comment: So using your code from above you dont get any error and get the plots ?

Comment: Using my code from above results in what you're asking for, yes. I have added the graph I get to my answer above.